# 'APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

```
create or replace procedure abcd123
as
V_ARR1 APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
begin
...
end;
```

compiling above code gives below errors

> Error(8,10): PLS-00201: identifier 'APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2'
>   must be declared 
>  Error(8,10): PL/SQL: Item ignored 
>   Error(12,2): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression
>   is incomplete or malformed 
>  Error(12,2): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   
>  Error(13,2): PL/SQL: Statement ignored 
>  Error(13,5):
>   PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is
>   incomplete or malformed

We tried recreating on a different DB but the issue does not occur.
Could someone suggest what is going wrong on the other DB.

Comment: You don't have APEX [installed](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e12196/overview.htm)? Try running `select comp_name, version from dba_registry` on both databases and spot the difference.

Comment: Missing a public synonym `apex_application_global` by the looks of it.